# Plugin: The Events Calendar Get Page Not Found

Tags: wordpress

I have installed "The Events Calendar" (http://wordpress.org/plugins/the-events-calendar/).

In "The Events Calendar Settings" section I checked "Show The Events Calendar link". When I go to my event page www.example.com/events/ it shows in title - page not found but in any case it shows the calendar.

Answer (score 0):

```
go your wordpress admin panel 

Event->setting

see the image setting enter your slug

after adding your slug this display like url.

Your current Events URL : XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

[image]

Comment: The slug used for building the events URL.Your current events URL is: http://www.example.com/events/. I click on this url and get Page not Found. Also I go to Permalinks, update them and got the same.

Comment: I have also realize that if I do not have any event today it brings page not found, if I add something it starts to work.

Comment: if you add event after work or not so define comment. thanks.

Comment: But in any case the problem is not fixed.

Comment: Setting->permalink->common setting  in select radio post name  option  or not define your site url.

Answer (score 0):

Settings > Permalinks [ re-save ] just press save Changes.